# Excel VBA Copy Operation (with Hidden Columns in-between)

Tags: vba, excel

I am stuck in a strange requirement. Following is a mock of my problem.

> In cell E1, I have value 1.
>
> In Cell F1, I have value 2.
>
> Column B is hidden.
>
> Now using VBA I need to copy E1 & F1 to Cell A1 such that A1 contain
>   "1" and C1 contains "2" (Because column B is hidden)
>
> In short I need to skip the hidden columns while pasting.

I know I can do 2 copy operations but number of hidden columns and number of cells to be copied is not same always. So I need to do the copy operation in one shot.

How to achieve this using Excel VBA?

Comment: It's not clear why you need to do the copy in a single operation. What's wrong with copying the two cells one after the other?

Comment: @TimWilliams: Because it is NOT fixed that each time I will need to copy 2 cells only. Also the number of columns hidden in between is also not fixed. Does it make sense now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Tester()
    CopySkippingHidden ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C1"), _
                       ActiveSheet.Range("F1")
End Sub


Sub CopySkippingHidden(rngToCopy As Range, pasteStart As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In rngToCopy.Cells
        Do While pasteStart.EntireColumn.Hidden
            Set pasteStart = pasteStart.Offset(0, 1)
        Loop
        c.Copy pasteStart
        Set pasteStart = pasteStart.Offset(0, 1)
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: If will if you do this: `For Each c in rngToCopy.Columns`